# Finding determinant of a matrix in an equation

Tags: matrices, determinant

Be A and B two matrix 3x3 and

$C=(-2A)^{3}\cdot (B^{2})^{-1}$

If det(A) = -2 and det(B) = 3

find det(C)

So, don't know how to approach this problem, how do I find a matrix knowing the determinant?

Comment: Use that $\det(XY)=\det(X)\det(Y)$, for $n\times n$ matrices $X,Y$ and that $\det(rX)=r^n\det(X)$ for $n\tiems n$ matrix $X$ and scalar $r$. A particular case of the first, for $Y=X^{-1}$, is that $1=\det(I)=\det(X)\det(X^{-1})$. So, $\det(X^{-1})=\det(X)^{-1}$.

Comment: You're not trying to find $C$, you're trying to find its determinant. Use the product formula: $\text{det} AB = \text{det} A \text{det} B$.

Comment: TomiMP, what did you try in order to solve your exercise ? Read [this thread](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question) and learn how to ask a good question on this site. Your post is being closed by moderators because it is a very bad and low-quality question. Moreover, you should learn to use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) in order to write formulas in an appropriate manner.

Comment: @NDB thank you very much

Comment: @Saegusa Thanks!! I need to play with the properties to find the det(C), now I get it. Thanks again

Comment: @Angelo I will not respond impolite users, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's follow the hints given in the comments to use $\det(AB) = \det(A)\det(B)$ and $\det(rA) = r^n\det(A)$ (if $A$ is $n \times n$). Also recall that $\det(A^{-1}) =\det(A)^{-1}$. Then,
\begin{align*}\det(C) &= \det((-2A)^3(B^2)^{-1})\\
&= \det((-2A)^3)\det((B^2)^{-1})\\
&= \det(-8A^3)\det(B^2)^{-1}\\
&=(-8)^3 \det(A)^3\det(B)^{-2}\\
&= (-8)^3 \cdot (-2^3) \cdot 3^{-2}\\
&= 4096/9
\end{align*}

Comment: Do not answer very low-quality questions.

Comment: Thank you!! my final answer was 4/9 hahah, I did something wrong. Much appreciated.